# multiple values in same field of database

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, jsp

since i am building a shopping a website how can a store the same product with different sizes as i don't want to create multiple rows..

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable
DETAIL  VARCHAR2(4000)  Yes  -   -
BRAND   VARCHAR2(4000)  Yes  -   -
IMAGE   VARCHAR2(4000)  Yes  -   -
PRICE   NUMBER  Yes  -   -
CATEGORY    VARCHAR2(4000)  Yes  -   -
PRODUCT_ID  VARCHAR2(2000)  Yes  -   -
SEARCH_ID   VARCHAR2(4000)  Yes  -   -
CLOTH_SIZE  VARCHAR2(4000)  Yes  -   -
```

here i want multiple clothsize values for the same column

Comment: simplest solution: delimit them with a comma Cloth_size= 2,3,4,5
Split them while reading data.

Comment: The correct solution is to have a separate table for clothes sizes, called an association/junction table. You really do not want to store them in a list within a row.  Bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))     
 {
    $json[]= array(
     'IMAGE' => $row['IMAGE'],
     'PRICE' => $row['PRICE']
    );
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

$jsonstring - add your data base this var.